# Javascript plug in Noty gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, undefined

I have the following javascript code:

```
function delete_draft(id, name) {
    var text = 'Are you sure you want to delete "' + name + '"?';
    alert(id + name)
    var noty = noty({
        text: text,
        buttons: [
        {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Yes', onClick: function($noty) {

            // this = button element
            // $noty = $noty element

            $noty.close();
            $.post('/ajax/drafts/delete', {id:id}, function(data) {
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
        }
        },
        {addClass: 'btn btn-danger', text: 'Cancel', onClick: function($noty) {
            $noty.close();
        }
        }
    ]});
}
```

When I run from the consul `delete_draft(6, "this is it")` I get this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "called_non_callable"
__proto__: Error
```

How can I fix this? The website for Noty is http://needim.github.com/noty/
If you think it should work, comment.

Comment: What is `noty` ? in code `var noty = noty` noty as function is undefined. May be you need `var noty = function(` ?

Comment: @Vsevolod That's why I put a link to the noty site at the bottum

Comment: @"Mike G" I can't open your link :-( How you plug the note.js in you html?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have just come across this problem. It turns out to be because the variable name `noty` is the same as the exported function name `noty`.

```
var n = noty({text: 'testing 123'});
```

Simply changing the variable name fixes it for me.

Comment: In the main page of noty they put the sample var noty = noty({... thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to renaming the variable **make sure you include the layout js file**. The default is top, so if it's not specified in the options you'll need to include `noty/layouts/top.js`. If you specify any other layouts include the appropriate layout js files.