# Noty plug in causes undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dialog, undefined

I'm working with a dialogue plug in called Noty( http://needim.github.com/noty/ ). I'm using it to create a confirm dialogue box. This is my code:

```
function delete_draft(id, name) {
    var text = 'Are you sure you want to delete "' + name + '"?';
    var noty = noty({
        text: text,
        buttons: [
        {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Yes', onClick: function($noty) {
            $.post('/ajax/drafts/delete', {id:id}, function(data) {
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        },
        {addClass: 'btn btn-danger', text: 'Cancel', onClick: function($noty) {
            $noty.close();
        }
        }
    ]});
}
```

When I call it using this `delete_draft(10, "test")` it give me:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "called_non_callable"
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: I've tried a series of alert statements to see how far the program is going, and what is begin run. I can try removing that line, but the alert statements seem to point to the idea that that line is never being executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript plug in Noty gives error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916261/javascript-plug-in-noty-gives-error)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions under multiple accounts.